# SSL enabled Nginx can't connect to Local Node JS Web Socket Server running on Port 80

Tags: nginx, ssl, ws

I have an Node JS websocket using npm module WS runing on Port 80 inside a Kubernetes Cluster.

The client is trying to connect to WebSocket over a Nginx proxy server which is outside the Kubernetes cluster but both WebSocket Node Server and Nginx Proxy server are on the same server.

The WebSocket call without ssl goes perfectly fine but when I enable ssl with it ,It doesnot work. I am not sure what is missing. It is my 2nd day looking at this issue. Couldnot find anything , any help would be appreciated

```
server {
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    listen 443 ssl;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;
    server_name servername;
    ssl on;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.3 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;
    ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;
    large_client_header_buffers 4 16k;
    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:10m; # a 1mb cache can hold about 4000 sessions, so we can hold 40000 sessions
    ssl_session_timeout  24h;
    keepalive_timeout 300; # up from 75 secs default

    ssl_certificate "<location>";
    ssl_certificate_key "<location>";


    location /ws{
          proxy_pass http://server-ip:80;
          proxy_http_version 1.1;
          proxy_set_header Upgrade websocket;
          proxy_set_header Connection upgrade;
    }
```

}

Comment: What does the failure look like?

Comment: I get an 500 internal server error

Comment: for wss you have to add ssl in wss.js

Comment: wss start with ssl
/**var options = {
 key: fs.readFileSync('/var/www/html/ssl/wss.key').toString(),
 cert: fs.readFileSync('/var/www/html/ssl/wss.pem').toString(),
 ca : fs.readFileSync('/var/www/html//ssl/wss.ca.crt').toString()
}*/

Comment: @RakeshGadhwal are you talking about the wss in the client?

Comment: But I dont want the websocket server to be ssl enabled on Port 443 because inside my kubernetes cluster I want it to work over Port 80. Is this something which is not possible?

Comment: yes in wss.js you have to add ssl conf

Comment: @soniakaushal
but in your conf nginx running on 443 ssl so is wss conf(websocket.js) also require SSL in conf

Comment: @RakeshGadhwal Check this Nginx Proxy Server settings . It says it can work without ssl on the websocket server 

https://www.nginx.com/blog/websocket-nginx/

Comment: Possible to add error messages?

Comment: @soniakaushal
issue is ws expose on 433 via Nginx so need to install SSL module in ws conf.
// websocket and http servers
var webSocketServer = require('websocket').server;
var http = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend make sure your config proper for SSL, looks like you are missing SSL cert & key into the Nginx side also are you sending cert & key from client side ?

```
ssl_certificate "<location>";
    ssl_certificate_key "<location>";
```

Here is refrence article you can follow setting up : https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-use-web-sockets-socket-io-with-digital-ocean-load-balancers-and-kubernetes-dok8s-with-e4dd5531c67e

Refrence Nginx ingress

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
 name: ws-socket
 annotations:
  kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "3600"
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "3600"
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippets: |
   location / {
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
spec:
 rules:
  - host: ws.example.com
   http:
    paths:
     - backend:
       serviceName: ws-socket
       servicePort: 80
```

You can SSL terminate at Nginx ingress level.

https://pumpingco.de/blog/using-signalr-in-kubernetes-behind-nginx-ingress/